# Minecraft Launcher doesn't Launch on Linux Mint

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux, minecraft-launcher

My computer crashed a few days ago and I had to reinstall the latest Linux Mint Version. Of course, I wanted to reinstall Minecraft so I downloaded the jar file from minecraft.net but if I type the launch command it gets the following output(I'm German so I'm going to translate the German output in Brackets)

```
    domiwald@Domi-System ~ $ java -jar /home/domiwald/Minecraft.jar 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6e600ba009, pid=15752, tid=15753
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/domiwald/hs_err_pid15752.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abgebrochen   (Translation: "Cancelled")
domiwald@Domi-System ~ $
```

I tried to tick the file as an executable but it still prints the same output.

Comment: [Seems similar to this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982396/failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled)

Comment: Not really... My question is why the error happens... Not why He doesnt write the Core Dump, but I thanks You Anyway ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try using java 8.0. Because I was having that crash and that worked for me. Here the commands to get java 8 on your computer. Or you can do it the old fashioned way. And go to java.com and extract the tarball and do it that way. But this is much easier to do in my opinion.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

I did this and it worked wonders.

Comment: Please do not invite people to run commands without context. Instead, point them towards a wiki page or the java8 project page. Additionally, this is a mint problem and not linked to minecraft (java is broken), and thus needs to be reported to mint directly. If there is an open ticket about this issue, point to it.

Comment: What do you mean with Java is broken?

Comment: BTW the Problem was in fact That Java 9.0 update, Which really crashed Minecraft! Thank You Olivia for your help ;)

Comment: Why did people downvote this It was correct!!!???!!!!!